# Is there a proper way to make responsive text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-markup

I've oftentimes had designers give me responsive designs where the wording of an element changes based on the size of the screen.

**Desktop**: Read more
**Mobile**: Read

**Desktop**: Download PDF
**Mobile**: Export

**Desktop**: Click here
**Mobile**: Tap here

What is the correct way to have different text in mobile and desktop versions of a website?

Comment: You can use JavaScript, or you can use media queries to show or hide certain elements on the page depending on resolution.

Comment: There is no one "correct way". It all depends on what you have to work with.

Comment: You can use bootstrap responsive utilities to achieve what you need very simply and clearly. Check: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Most responsive frameworks have a class name you add for X size. Put text in separate spans and add that class.

Comment: the problem with such utility classes is that they do not really obfuscate the content from all screen readers (some still read elements with `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;`) - accessibility issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use media queries, pseudo classes and some ingenuity for this:

```css
a[data-mobiletext] {
    background-color: #FC0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    a[data-mobiletext] {
        background-color: #CF0;
    }
    a[data-mobiletext] span {
        display: none;
    }
    a[data-mobiletext]:after {
        content: attr(data-mobiletext);
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="/" data-mobiletext="Read"><span>Read more</span></a>
<a href="/" data-mobiletext="Export"><span>Download PDF</span></a>
<a href="/" data-mobiletext="Tap here"><span>Click here</span></a>
```

Click "Full Page" to view Desktop version.

Comment: This CSS-only approach is very clean. I'd be interested in knowing if there was a way to allow the width to automatically conform itself. Considering the text is set in the CSS, setting a width manually shouldn't be a big issue. But it'd be nice not to need to.

Comment: Wrap the link text inside a span element so that it is easier to manipulate via CSS. I'll revise my answer shortly.

Comment: CSS generated text is not announced by screen readers so with this technique AT users will get no text at all.

Comment: @steveax the span contains the longer text. I have set it to `display: none` for demonstration; [alternate techniques](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) could be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches I've used where clients have made similar requests (and not been talked out of it*):

1) Use Javascript to change the text based on screen width / device detection methods;

2) Set the default text as your preferred choice, and wrap it in a span or similar, use the text that you think is best on all devices (best for SEO / content / screen readers depending on priority) then use pseudo selectors e.g. :before with the content: '' property to set alternative text based on media queries. Hiding the default span/element as appropriate.

(*) I would say consider your content and see if you can find a universal label for these items is probably better practice though.

Comment: Kudos on the footnote ;)

Comment: Thanks - we've all been there with these kind of requests... so hopefully was helpful first :)